# How to generate shadow file for specifically Linux

Tags: linux, password, accounts

Can i  generate shadow file for linux system whith known password?
Why I need this? These file copy in my initramfs system(when kernel build) and when i boot it on my odroid board it ask login and password, but i cannot change my password in initramfs, but i can when the kernel build.

Comment: the easiest way is copy your existing shadow file.

Comment: @IporSircer yes now i do it, but i need scrypt or some another way to do it when the kernel build.Not copy my passwd file.

Comment: Are you changing your password on each build?

Comment: @meuh if i need to change password when linux start -yes.I cant change passwod use passwd because i hane initramfs fs.And only way to do it, i think (mybe i wrong), change passwd file when i builg my img.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would need to do this more than once, but you can generate the sha512 encrypted password entry field found in a `/etc/shadow` file (the thing beginning `$6$...`) using

```
python -c 'import crypt
print(crypt.crypt("test", crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))'
```

where `test` is the cleartext password in this example.